# ¿Cómo seleccionar lo mismo en una lista desplegable y que se ejecute cada vez que se selecciona?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, lista, motor-de-juego

Tengo un juego `(piedra,papel,tijera)` que cada vez que un usuario selecciona un opción de estas, se ejecuta un código que lo que hace es que diga si ganaste o perdiste, partidas ganadas , etc.

El problema es que una vez que el usuario por ejemplo selecciona piedra y juega, y luego quiere seleccionar piedra de nuevo, en el segundo intento no se ejecuta nada, y para que funcione tiene que cambiar de opción, les adjunto código.

El evento `onclick` (no me funciona ya que cuando el usuario abre la lista también realiza una selección involuntaria).

**HTML**

```
<select id="Opciones" onchange="elijo()">
  <<option disabled="seleccion"></option>
  <option value="piedra">piedra
  <option value="papel">papel
  <option value="tijera">tijera
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function elijo() {
  let opcion = document.getElementById("Opciones").value;
   document.getElementById("resultadoEleccion").innerHTML = "Elegiste: " + opcion;
  let opcionPc = elijepc();
  document.getElementById("resultadoEleccionPC").innerHTML = "PC : " + opcionPc ;
  jugar(opcion,opcionPc);
}
```

[image: asi se ve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes ponerle una opción que aparezca seleccionada por defecto cuando se crea el elemento, con una etiqueta que indique al usuario la opción que debe hacer. Así es como suelen funcionar los combobox o select, de esa forma además te ahorras tener que poner una etiqueta (label) a la izquierda, indicando para qué sirve ese combobox. Imagínate en un formulario con varios tipos de elementos, lo que se hace casi siempre es indicar dentro del mismo select con una etiqueta lo que se debe elegir dentro de él.

Luego, mediante un `if` puedes validar para asegurarte de que se están eligiendo una de las opciones válidas para iniciar el juego.

**Nota**: He comentado el código que llama a funciones que no has compartido, para evitar el error en el script.

Ejemplo:

```js
function elijo() {
  let opcion = document.getElementById("Opciones").value;
  if (opcion!="Elija para jugar") {
     document.getElementById("resultadoEleccion").innerHTML = "Elegiste: " + opcion;
//       let opcionPc = elijepc();
//       document.getElementById("resultadoEleccionPC").innerHTML = "PC : " + opcionPc ;
//       jugar(opcion,opcionPc);
  }else{
     document.getElementById("resultadoEleccion").innerHTML = "Debes elegir una opción válida";

  }
}
```

```html
<select id="Opciones" onchange="elijo()">
  <<option selected="seleccion">Elija para jugar</option>
  <option value="piedra">piedra
  <option value="papel">papel
  <option value="tijera">tijera
</select>
<div id="resultadoEleccion"></div>
<hr />
<div id="resultadoEleccionPC"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Parte del problema puede tener que ver con el uso de let, [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) se menciona que es algo nuevo y que no todos los navegadores ofrecen soporte.

Por otro lado, es lógico que si el usuario selecciona una opción no seleccionada se genera el evento **change** y se ejecuta **elijo**, mientras que si vuelve a hacer click sobre la misma opción, no se genera el evento **change** y no se ejecuta **elijo**. Una posible solución la tienes en la 5ta respuesta que aparece [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome).

Comment: Deberías de dar un ejemplo funcional como lo hace @A-Cedano